# postgres rows to 2 dimensional array

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

Is there any easy way of converting a postgres table in to an 2 dimensional?

I have a data table foobar with two columns foo and bar which has the following data in 
1,2
3,4
5,6

I want to convert it in

```
{ 
{1,2},
{3,4},
{5,6}
}
```

I have tried things like

select ARRAY[foo,bar] from foobar

which creates

```
{1,2}
{3,4}
{5,6}
```

Which is nearly there

I suspect that I am going to have to write pgpsql function to do this?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did for LedgerSMB:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE compound_array (
        BASETYPE = ANYARRAY,
        STYPE = ANYARRAY,
        SFUNC = ARRAY_CAT,
        INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

Then you can:

```
select compound_array(ARRAY[[foo,bar]]) from foobar;
```

Note you need to have two pairs of square brackets because otherwise it just adds them in a one dimensional array.

Comment: Starting with postgresql 9.5, you can also do this with array_agg. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function my_array()
returns integer[] as $function$
declare
    r record;
    a integer[];
begin

    for r in 
        select foo, bar
        from (values
            (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
        ) foobar (foo, bar)
    loop
        a := a || array[[r.foo, r.bar]];
    end loop;

    return a;

end;
$function$ language plpgsql;

select my_array();
      my_array       
---------------------
 {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}

select (my_array())[2][2];
 my_array 
----------
        4
```

Comment: Much easier to create an aggregate based on existing PostgreSQL functions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select array_agg(ARRAY[foo,bar]) from foobar
```